# What is the most efficient way to get number of one-to-many relations in EF Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

### Question's context

In Entity Framework Core, I have two models: `CreatorPost` & `Like`. Each post can have infinite likes, but each like only belongs to one post; a one-to-many relation:

```
public class CreatorPost
{
    ...
}
```

```
public class Like
{
    ...
    public CreatorPost CreatorPost { get; set; }
}
```

In the posts' display, I get the number of their likes this way:

```
int likes = _context.Likes.Where (l => l.CreatorPost == creatorPost).Count ();
```

As all likes of all posts are stored in one table, so after a while, when they become more, querying the likes count will take longer & longer.

### The Solution

The solution that I tried was to add another column to `CreatorPost`, an integer which saves the count of likes:

```
public class CreatorPost
{
    ...
    public uint Likes { get; set; } // Added this
}
```

Then, when I want to get the *count* of likes of a post, instead of querying all likes, I just retrieve this value. And in the `LikeCreatorPost ()` method, which was used to *add* likes to the database, I added a piece of code to add one to the `Likes` property as well.

Till now it's ok for getting the count of likes, but in the `LikeCreatorPost ()` method I want to ensure that a user cannot like twice, I still have to query all the likes and check for that.

---

I'm aware that also caching pages is possible, but my question is how much adding another column to the database instead of querying all of the likes can improve the application's performance (because adding one column will make the database larger and impact performance)? Does that worth it? Is there any better solution to make it more efficient?

Comment: "As all likes of all posts are stored in one table, so after a while, when they become more, querying the likes count will take longer & longer." Do you currently have a performance problem? 
In my experience, you should only expect performance problems counting from this kind of table only after it reaches tens of millions of records - so unless you've done something really wrong, I wouldn't be worried about performance of count just yet.

Comment: What - having `Likes` in `Like`? This makes no sense. And even if it is in `CreatorPost`, still doesn't make much sense, since `Like` should have **indexed** FK column `CreatorPostId`, so counting for specific `CreatorPost.Id` should be very fast, regardless of the `Likes` table size. This is how all relational databases store and query "collections" for years, so no reason for "not working for you".

Comment: @IvanStoev thank you for informing me of that little *fatal* problem

Comment: So @ZoharPeled do you mean that I should not be worried about that for now?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm saying.

Comment: However, performance might be affected not by Count, but by the ORM playing a role of middleware between the database and the application. Each time you need to calculate the total number of likes, your code will execute an extra query. Imagine, you need to show 100 posts on the same page. If you fetch posts without counting likes, then your code will build and execute 100+1 sql queries. If there are 100 client fetching those 100 posts, then there 10K+ sql queries instead of plain 100 queries fetching posts. This might become a bottleneck in some circumstances, especially under high load.

Answer (score 1):

You are right that on-demand calculation might become a problem on a large dataset. However, there are several options that can help to solve it. The approach depends on your particular system. Here are some of them.

1. Adding an extra column to your model is not a problem. However, you should modify your model a bit, so that it is responsible for the calculation itself (Domain Driven Design). Using this approach, the calculated field always reflects the correct number of likes.

```
    public class CreatorPost
    {
        private IList<Like> likes = // initialize
    
        public IEnumerable<Like> Likes => likes;
    
        public uint LikeCount { get; private set; }
    
        public void AddLike()
        {
            likes.Add(new Like(this, ...));
            LikeCount++;
        }
    
        public void RemoveLike(...)
        {
            var like = likes.Where(...);
            likes.Remove(like);
            LikeCount--;
        }
    }
    
    public class Like
    {
        public Like(CreatorPost post, ...)
        {
            CreatorPost = post;
            // initialize other properties
        }

        public CreatorPost CreatorPost { get; init; }
    }
```

2. Create a view in your database, so that the view has a calculated column summarizing the number of likes. Then, map the view to the CreatorPost class. Using this approach, CreatorPost always gets the correct number of likes without extra queries to the database. However, keep in mind that tables should be properly indexed on filtered columns.

Comment: "on demand calculation might become a problem on a large dataset" - Well, Count isn't the type of "on demand calculation" that could cause that kind of a problem, unless by the words "large dataset" you mean tens of millions.

Comment: Mostly I mean performance problems caused by the ORM itself, because it runs multiple queries counting likes for multiple posts instead of a single query returning likes for multiple posts.